# Bapat–Beg theorem for two order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, order-statistics

[Bapat–Beg theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bapat%E2%80%93Beg_theorem) gives the joint probability distribution of order statistics of independent but not necessarily identically distributed random variables in terms of the cumulative distribution functions.

I have troubles formulating the case of two order statistics $X_{(1)} \le X_{(2)}$ from the general one. Is this correct?

$$F_{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}}(x_1, x_2) = \frac{P_{n_1}(x_1) + P_{n_2}(x_2)}{n_1! (n_2 - n_1)! \times (n_2 - n_2)! }$$

Comment: Very interested in this, and in your follow-on question below.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote doesn’t make much sense. On the left, you chose $k=2$, $n_1=1$ and $n_2=2$, but on the right you have $n_1$ and $n_2$ as free variables. (Also $(n_2-n_2)!=0!=1$.)

Substituting $k=2$, $n_1=1$ and $n_2=2$ into the definition in the Wikipedia article you linked to yields

\begin{eqnarray}
F_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}}(x_1,x_2)
&=&
\operatorname{Pr}\left(X_{(1)}\le x_1\land\operatorname{Pr}(X_{(2)}\le x_2\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{i_2=2}^n\sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2}\frac{P_{i_1,i_2}(x_1,x_2)}{i_1!(i_2-i_1)!(n-i_2)!}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

where

$$
P_{i_1,i_2}(x_1,x_2)=
\operatorname{per}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
F_1(x_1)                \;\cdots\;  F_1(x_1)               & 
F_1(x_2)-F_1(x_1) \;\cdots\;  F_1(x_2)-F_1(x_1) & 
1-F_1(x_2)             \;\cdots\;  1-F_1(x_2)  \\
F_2(x_1)                 \;\cdots\;  F_2(x_1)                & 
F_2(x_2)-F_2(x_1)  \;\cdots\;  F_2(x_2)-F_2(x_1)   & 
1-F_2(x_2)             \;\cdots\;  1-F_1(x_2)\\
\vdots                                                            &    
\vdots                                                            &              
\vdots                                                  \\
\underbrace{F_n(x_1)               \;\cdots\;  F_n(x_1)              }_{i_1}   & 
\underbrace{F_n(x_2)-F_n(x_1)\;\cdots\;F_n(x_2)-F_n(x_1)}_{i_2-i_1} & 
\underbrace{1-F_n(x_2) \;\cdots\; 1-F_n(x_2) }_{n-i_2}
\end{bmatrix}\;.
$$

I’m not sure whether you also intended to set $n=2$. In that case, the result is

$$
F_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}}(x_1,x_2)
=\sum_{i=1}^2\frac{P_{i,2}(x_1,x_2)}i\;,
$$

where

$$
P_{i,2}(x_1,x_2)=
\operatorname{per}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
F_1(x_1)                \;\cdots\;  F_1(x_1)               & 
F_1(x_2)-F_1(x_1) \;\cdots\;  F_1(x_2)-F_1(x_1)\\
\underbrace{F_2(x_1)                 \;\cdots\;  F_2(x_1)}_i                & 
\underbrace{F_2(x_2)-F_2(x_1)  \;\cdots\;  F_2(x_2)-F_2(x_1)}_{2-i}
\end{bmatrix}\;.
$$

Writing out the sum yields

\begin{eqnarray}
F_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}}(x_1,x_2)
&=&F_1(x_1)(F_2(x_2)-F_2(x_1))+F_2(x_1)(F_1(x_2)-F_1(x_1))+F_1(x_1)F_2(x_1)
\\
&=&
F_1(x_1)F_2(x_2)+F_2(x_1)F_1(x_2)-F_1(x_1)F_2(x_1)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

That makes sense, as it adds the two ways in which the order statistics can be related to the variables ($X_{(1)}=X_1$ and $X_{(2)}=X_2$ or $X_{(1)}=X_2$ and $X_{(2)}=X_1$) and then subtracts the double-counted contribution where both variables are below $x_1$.

Comment: I intended two random variables of order statistics $X_{(1)} \le X_{(2)}.$ Am I right to say your latter part of the proof suffices in this case for $F_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}}(x_1,x_2)?$ I hope $F_{X_{(1)}}$ and $F_{X_{(2)}}$ are CDFs, because of the permanent matrix? I also found a similar [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498741/order-statistics-of-independent-but-non-identical-uniform-distribution) which is different to this approach. What I want is the uniform distribution for non-IID order statistics. Between Bepat-Beg theorem and the other link, which one is appropriate? Thanks!